# Does Spark clear memory before going to the next loop iteration?

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, executor

I am parsing files via partitions using for loops in pyspark. I have 7 partitions and each partition is about 300GB in size which is the reason I am using for loop.

But when it comes to about the 4 or 5th loop, it starts giving a lot of fails (I see that in the spark UI) and suddenly resets the loop and starts from the first partition all over again.
After some time, the entire job fails.

It is as if, Spark does not clear the executors memory before going to the next loop iteration. Is that the case? If so how do I manually clear the memory?

Im just learning about Garbage Collection in spark. Could it be that it exceeded max GC memory?

Thank You

Comment: Spark API will allow you to read multiple file under a single partitions and multiple partitions. You don’t have to apply loops. Can’t you use that instead of applying loops?

Comment: I am loading the entire parquet via a particular partition and therefore using a loop. If I load all the partitions at once, I get OOM

Comment: I have the same question/setup — did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: I used the `unpersist()` function to remove data from the dataframes. I also did the calculations needed for min number of executors, memory etc based on the data size i was parsing. Choosing the right GC helps, but in my case, my method was wrong, and I had to change the data i was feeding each loop.